# How to convert string to date time

Tags: c#, asp.net, datetime

```
 string value =     "Sat Apr 28 2012 11:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)"
```

I need to convert to date time

I tried doing:

```
 DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm", null);
```

or

```
 DateTime datetime2 = Convert.ToDateTime(value);
```

Exception: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string doesn't match your format.

You need to parse that string a bit before trying to convert it. For example, "Apr 28 2012 11:00:00" could be parsed. But, you'll need to convert the rest of it yourself.

You may want to look into using `DateTimeOffset` [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetimeoffset.aspx), because it can hold time relative to UTC, like your string.

Found this is the documentation, pretty close to what you have

```
// Parse date and time with custom specifier.
dateString = "Sun 15 Jun 2008 8:30 AM -06:00";
format = "ddd dd MMM yyyy h:mm tt zzz";
try
{
    result = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(dateString, format, provider);
    Console.WriteLine("{0} converts to {1}.", dateString, result.ToString());
}
catch (FormatException)
{
   Console.WriteLine("{0} is not in the correct format.", dateString);
}
```

Comment: While that's "pretty close" to the original string, the difference in terms of time zone identifier, offset specifier etc is likely to prove painful. (I also suspect it's HH:mm:ss format, not `h:mm tt`. I'd also suggest using `TryParseExact` rather than catching FormatException...)

Answer (score 3):

You're specifying a format of `MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm" but your string isn't in that format even *slightly*.

I suspect you'll have trouble with the "GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)" part - the rest is in a format of "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss" or "ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss" if the day-of-month number *isn't* always two digits.

I suggest you parse the offset from UTC separately, and create a `DateTimeOffset` - parse the first part (before GMT) as an *unspecified* `DateTime` - and then parse the offset. EDIT: You can parse the offset with `TimeSpan.ParseExact` but you'll need to handle the sign yourself, I believe - I can't see any documented way of parsing a negative timespan that way :(

EDIT: Note that my [Noda Time](http://noda-time.googlecode.com) project *would* allow you to parse the offset part, e.g. with a pattern of "'GMT'+HHmm" - and obviously we'd cope with the `LocalDateTime` part - but you'd still need to separate the different parts of the string from each other. Sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using NodaTime;
using NodaTime.Text;

public class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        string text = "Sat Apr 28 2012 11:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)";
        ZonedDateTime parsed = Parse(text);
        Console.WriteLine(parsed);
    }

    static readonly LocalDateTimePattern LocalPattern =
        LocalDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantInfo("ddd MMM d yyyy HH:mm:ss");

    // Note: Includes space before GMT for convenience later
    static readonly OffsetPattern OffsetPattern =
        OffsetPattern.CreateWithInvariantInfo("' GMT'+HHmm");

    static ZonedDateTime Parse(string text)
    {
        int gmtIndex = text.IndexOf(" GMT");
        int zoneIndex = text.IndexOf(" (");
        // TODO: Validation that these aren't -1 :)

        string localText = text.Substring(0, gmtIndex);
        string offsetText = text.Substring(gmtIndex, zoneIndex - gmtIndex);

        var localResult = LocalPattern.Parse(localText);
        var offsetResult = OffsetPattern.Parse(offsetText);

        // TODO: Validate that both are successful

        var fixedZone = DateTimeZone.ForOffset(offsetResult.Value);        
        return localResult.Value.InZoneStrictly(fixedZone);
    }
}
```

Note that this will give a `ZonedDateTime` in a *fixed* time zone - not really Eastern time. Currently Noda Time doesn't have an `OffsetDateTime`, which would be a natural fit here...

Comment: Could this be a job for Noda Time? :)

Comment: @mattytommo: Not yet, to be honest. We could parse the offset and the local date time parts separately, but there's no ZonedDateTime text handling yet. It gets *really* messy. Will edit.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following:

```
Convert.ToDateTime("Sat Apr 28 2012 11:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)".Substring(4, 20))
```

Answer (score 1):

try `ddd MMM d yyyy hh:mm:ss zzz`

If it's not working try [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx), what you have is just a variant of this format:

```
"ddd MMM dd yyyy h:mm:ss zzz"
```

Only there are some extra pieces in it:

```
"ddd MMM dd yyyy h:mm:ss GMTzzz (blah blah blah)"
```

If you deal with those, you should be fine:

```
value = value.Remove(value.IndexOf(" ("));
DateTime datetime = DateTime.ParseExact(value, "ddd MMM dd yyyy hh:mm:ss \"GMT\"zzz", null);
```