# get date and time from the string

Tags: c#, datetime, timezone

I've a string `Wed Sep 23 2015 15:30:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)` in this format. How can I get the date Sep 23 2015 and time 15.30 from it. I tried following, but it throws an invalid format exception.

```
 DateTime dt=   DateTime.Parse(apptViewModel.strAppintmentDate).Date;
 TimeSpan tm = DateTime.Parse(apptViewModel.strAppintmentTime).TimeOfDay;
```

Timezone is not important in this string. And I don't have to convert date from one time zone to another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `Wed Sep 23 2015 15:30:00 GMT` try this

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("Wed Sep 23 2015 15:30:00 GMT", "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'K", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

For `Wed Sep 23 2015 15:30:00 GMT-0400` try this

```
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact("Wed Sep 23 2015 15:30:00 GMT-0400", "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

If `(Eastern Daylight Time)` is included into date string, then try this

```
var dateString = "Wed Sep 23 2015 15:30:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)";
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(dateString.Replace("(Eastern Daylight Time)", string.Empty).Trim(), "ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss 'GMT'zzz", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But you can also use NodaTime.
See Jon Skeet answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10197437/how-to-convert-string-to-date-time).

Comment: it gives exception `An exception of type 'System.FormatException' occurred in mscorlib.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.`

Comment: `(Eastern Daylight Time)` is included in your date string?

Comment: Just for knowledge sake, what is `GMT` and `zzz`?